# State machine for a web framework?

Tags: php

I have recently began learning about state machines, and i have one question: Can the workflow of a web framework be modelled using a finite state machine?

The reason i consider this to be a possibility is that between receiving the request and delivering the informations, there are definitively a set of states (initializing the request, routing the request, dispatching it and displaying the information -  in a very simplified form).

Thanks.

Comment: you seem to have answered your question already. yes, you have a set of states that you have listed and transitions between them.

Comment: The HTTP protocol (and also the underlying TCP protocol) is defined as a state machine somehow. Read the HTTP standard RFCs.

Comment: Pretty much any computational system can be modeled as a state machine, although in some cases the number of states may be so large as to be impractical to enumerate.

Comment: True, but as i keep reading, i come to the conclusion that it's more like a chaining of actions. There is no external event causing the state to jump forward/backwards, so i guess duskwuff's answer is pretty much on spot. However, it can be modelled and controlled through a process that looks like a state machine. Guess i still need alot of learning. It still looks like a decent way to implement a web framework, but basicly, it is just glueing some components together (with the advantage of being able to replace them/eliminate them at any point depending on needs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in any useful sense.

The workflow you're describing is really just a set of stages in request processing. While this may technically fit the definition of a state machine, the transitions involved are all largely unconditional (each stage always transitions to the next one, unless an error occurs), so it's not particularly helpful to model it as a state machine.

Comment: This was the reason I was asking the question. Because as i said i am just starting to investigate state machines, and i felt like something was slipping and didn't look right. Your answer makes it a little clearer for me to understand why not use a state machine.